# iOS Touch instead of touchDown?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to set a touch event on a little synthesizer keyboard I am making but I can only connect a "touch down" event onto a button I've made.

How would I set a "touch" onto a button? So let's say someone pressed a key down and slides there finger across the other buttons... you'd expect the other keys to play on a "touch" like a piano, right? Not sure how to achieve this in Interface Builder.

Any help would be fantastic - thanks!
Sean

Comment: Isn't what you're describing is essentially "touch down"?

Comment: Essentially - yes... but a "touch down" would need a touch to begin with. If you have a succesion of 4 buttons and you touch down on the first one that is technically the only "touch down" so when you slide your finger across the other ones... they are not triggered.  Make sense?

Comment: So you're trying to play "glissando" on the piano, right? Now that's a different kind of thing. (I'm using gloves for that else it hurts - bad technique, I know...) Well, to the topic: I'd say you'd be better off drawing the piano without the buttons, and detecting the sliding movement of the finger with a transparent overlay view. Is that something of a reasonable solution?

Comment: Hrmm - and good tutorials on how I could do this if it's not possible with interface builder? I can't think of how I would do it...

Comment: use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or simply subclass `UIView` and implement the `touchedMoved:withEvent:` (etc.) methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire up more than just the touchDown event. In order to achieve what you want, you'll need to listen not only to the initial touch with a "down" event, but you'll also need to make your app aware of "move" and "touch up" events so you can appropriately respond to a user moving their fingers around. And even further, it would be difficult to try and make each button respond independently to these movements by placing all the code within a button subclass, for example.

Instead, you'll want to create a single point of code that can look at all the buttons at once, receive touches the user is making, and make decisions based on those touches on what to do. This will be the task of your view controller that contains all the buttons.

Within this view controller, you can make use of the `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, and `touchesEnded:` methods. You should then employ hit testing to check to see what buttons the touches are on. Look at the `convertPoint:`, `hitTest:withEvent:` and `pointInside:withEvent:` to perform tests on buttons.

Essentially within these touch methods, you will track when a new button is pressed in `touchDown:`, when a touch moves to a new button in `touchesMoved:`, as well as what button the touch just came from, and when a user stops the touch in `touchesEnded:`. By putting all of this together, you can write the code that will keep track of each finger movement, what button its over, and when to play sounds for those buttons.

Again, I would advise against trying to place all your code in individual touch handlers from button actions. Instead, make use of your view controller to manage the touches among all your buttons at once.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look into iOS events

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65

It sounds like you want `UIControlEventTouchDown` which will play while you currently are pressing down on a button or area.
Conversely, you can use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` which will play once you lift up on a button or area.

something like `[results addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

That assumes each touch has a corresponding down and up action.

If you are looking for something like running your hands across a piano, you could try possibly using a Pan gesture and keeping track of the location of the swipe would work.

Comment: I don't think UIControlEventTouchDownInside exists

Comment: Thnx Tieme!  I can touchDragInside, but not touchDownInside.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIControl Class Reference - UIControlEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65).

You are looking for `UIControlEventTouchDown`

```
//For example:
UIButton *myButon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[myButon addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: Essentially - yes... but a "touch down" would need a touch to begin with. If you have a succesion of 4 buttons and you touch down on the first one that is technically the only "touch down" so when you slide your finger across the other ones... they are not triggered. Make sense?  http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xmpxhh_glissando-piano-technique_music#.UOhn1InjljY  (watch @ 0:17)